# SmtpClient exception not stepping into SmtpFailedRecipientsException

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, try-catch, smtpclient

I am trying to show an error message for failed recipients in my asp.net webpage. For some reason the code is not stepping into the SmtpFailedRecipientException:

---

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.server.com", 25) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("any@one.com", "123456") };

    using (var message = new MailMessage { })
    {
        message.From = new MailAddress(salesPersonDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text);
        message.To.Add(mailToTextBox.Text);
        message.CC.Add(mailToCCTextBox.Text);
        message.CC.Add(mailToCCTextBox2.Text);
        message.CC.Add(mailToCCTextBox3.Text);
        message.Subject = mailSubjectTextBox.Text;
        message.Body = mailBodyTextBox.Text;
    
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
    
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {
            string strSmtpFailedRecipientsException = "test";
        }
    
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             string strException = "test";
        }
    }
```

The code is stepping properly into the the second "catch" but for some reason no into the SmtpFailedRecipientsException. Anyone can tell what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by myself.

The SmtpFailedRecipientsException is for exceptions with two or more failed recipients - and in my case I always had only one failed recipient.

For one failed recipient I had to use the SmtpFailedRecipientException.